# prove that $f^{-1} = f*$ as follow

Tags: functions, inverse-function

**edit:**

Let $f: A \to B$. Let $f*$ be the inverse relation, i.e.
\begin{equation*}
f* = \{(y,x) \in B \times A \mid f(x)=y \}.
\end{equation*}
Show that if $f* : B \to A$ is a function,
then $f^{-1} = f*$.

**Attempt:**

Let $f*: B \to A$ be a function.
Then, $f$ is bijective and hence $f$ is invertible, i.e. $f$ have an inverse, say $f^{-1}$.
It is clear that $f^{-1} \circ f = i_A$
and $f \circ f* = i_B$ where $i$ is the identity function. Hence,
\begin{equation*}
f^{-1} = f^{-1} \circ i_B = f^{-1} \circ (f \circ f*) = (f^{-1} \circ f) \circ f* = i_A \circ f* = f*.
\end{equation*}
Thus, $f^{-1} = f$.

Is the above correct?

Comment: Since $i = f^{-1}\circ f : A \to A$ is the identity function *on* $A$, how is defined $f^{-1}\circ i$? Also, $f \circ f^*$ is the identity function *on* $B$, it is not the same as $i$.

Comment: I assume your defintion of $f^{-1}$ is "any left-inverse"? And instead of "It is clear that", you may argue more explicitly where you use the fact that $f^*$ is a function.

Comment: Suggestion for improvement: Compute the relation(!) compositions $f^*\circ f\subseteq A\times A$ and $f\circ f^*\subseteq B\times B$ and see what happens when both $f$ and $f^*$ are functions

Comment: The question is missing a proper definition of $f^{-1}$. I will not settle for "the usual definition of the inverse".

Comment: What is the connection of the title with the question ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust from $f^{-1} = f*$ isn't it?

Comment: @azif00 $f^{-1}$ is the inverse of $f$

Comment: Which of my comments does this address ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust the connection

Comment: Your question is *not* about uniqueness, is it ?

Comment: ah, yes. i've make a mistake here. it's not the uniqueness of inverse

Comment: since $f^{-1}$ be the inverse of $f$, it is implies that $f$ is invertible, right?

Comment: since $f*$ is a function, then $f$ is bijective i.e. invertible i.e. have an inverse, right?

Comment: @azif00 how about now?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First, suppose that $f*$ is a function. That means that each for each $y \in B, \exists!x \in A$ such that $f^*(y)=x.$ Then $(f^* \circ f)(x) = f^*(f(x)) = f^*(y)=x,$ and similarly, $(f \circ f^*)(y) =f(f^*(y))= f(x)=y$, so $f*$ is the inverse of $f$. Or perhaps I should say $f*$ is *an* inverse of $f$, since you've also been tasked with proving the uniqueness of the inverse.

To prove that the inverse of f is unique, suppose that f has two inverses, g and h. We need to show that g=h. Since g is the inverse of f, that means $g∘f=id_A$  and $f∘h=id_B$. Then $g=g∘id_B=g∘(f∘h)=(g∘f)∘h=id_A∘h=h$.

Comment: but, how to prove $f^{-1} = f*$.

Comment: Is my answer above correct?

Comment: Yes, the basic proof that $f*$ is an inverse of $f$ is correct, you just needed the uniqueness part. And at the end, did you mean to put "Thus, $f^{-1} = f^*$"?

Comment: N1 bro, thanks for give another views.

Comment: What if I write $f* \circ f = id_A$ and $f \circ f* = id_B$, is that true?

Comment: yes, i did. ${}{}{}$

Comment: yes, both of those equations are true.

Comment: thans a lot! (y)

Comment: now, which one should I use? is mine above correct? or still false?

Comment: You could use either one since they are both correct. So you could just pick whichever one is more similar in style to the way the professor does examples in class.

Comment: Thanks again broo!!!